# Multiple DBContexts in Linq Query

Tags: asp.net-core

I have to pull data from two database tables. for example, blog from DBContext1, url from DBContext2.table1, directory info from DBContext2.table2. I create join linq query but the error message says "InvalidOperationException: Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance." Below is my code, please help! Thanks.

appsettings.json

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=db1;User ID=user1;Password=pw1;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=true;",
        "SecondaryConnection": "Data Source=server2;Initial Catalog=db2;User ID=user2;Password=pw2;Encrypt=False;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
    }
```

```
public partial class DBContext1 : DbContext{
 public DBContext1()
        {
        }

        public DBContext1(DbContextOptions<DBContext2> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
public DBContext2()
        {
        }

        public DBContext2(DbContextOptions<DBContext2> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

```
Programs.cs
```

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext1>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});
//add connectionstring
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext2>(options =>
{
    
   options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:SecondaryConnection"]);
});
```

```
HomeController.cs
```

```
private readonly DBContext1 _dbContext1;
private readonly DBContext2 _dbContext2;

 public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,DBContext1 dbContext1, DBContext2 dbContext2)
        {
            
            _dbContext1 = dbContext1;
            _dbontext2= dbContext2;
        }

public IActionResult Details(string?fname, string?lname)
        {
            //get list
            var blogInfo=_dbContext1.Directories.ToList();
            var Staff = (from person in _dbContext2.directoryData
                         join url in _dbContext2.URLs

                         on person.EMPLID equals url.EMPLID
                         //    join blog in _dbContext1.Directories
                         //  on person.Email equals blog.email into temp
                         //   from subset in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          where person.LAST_NAME.StartsWith(lname) && person.FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(fname) 

                         where person.LAST_NAME == lname && person.FIRST_NAME == fname
                         orderby person.LAST_NAME, person.FIRST_NAME, person.middle_name
                         select new Person
                         {
                             
                             Last_name = person.LAST_NAME,
                             First_name = person.FIRST_NAME,
                            
                              Web = url.URL,
                             // Blog=subset.blog
                         }).ToList();
            if(Staff!=null){
             Staff.Blog= blogInfo.Find(a => a.email.Equals(Staff.Email)).ToString();
       }
            return View(Staff);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of using two DbContexts as using two databases.

Entity Framework does not support Cross database queries.

Your best bet would be to either:

1. use a stored procedure
2. resolve one of the queries to an actual list of rendered values by using `.ToList()` and use that in the other query. (be sure you use Eager Loading)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I changed my code to get a list first for DBContext1. But I got a different error "SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"  Does aps.net Core not allow to connect two database?

Comment: Firstly, slow down and read that error message it tells you exactly what's wrong . Secondly, you might benefit from learning how SSL works.it has nothing to do with .Net

Comment: I use a spreadsheet data for DBContext1 and read DBContext2 from SQL server to solve this problem. Thanks for the help!